# RecyclerView внутри RecyclerView

Tags: android, массивы, recyclerview

Доброго времени суток. 
Как можно осуществить RecyclerView внутри RecyclerView? 
Я думал сделать с помощью Массива, мол, под каждый новый Item создаётся отдельный RV; или с помощью "Общего", который просто меняет список и данные в зависимости от выбранного элемента.
*(рисунки для наглядности)* 
Внешний RV
[image: TopLvl RV]

Внутренний
[image: DeepLvl RV]

Comment: Зачем Вам это? О.о

Comment: Нужно для проекта, да и просто для общего развития :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться советами выше, но от себя могу добавить следующее: не стоит так делать с `RecyclerView`.

---

С очень большой вероятностью возникнут проблемы в работе (как минимум, с производительностью при большом кол-ве `RecyclerView`) и со 100% вероятностью возникнет проблема с грязным и тяжело поддерживаемым кодом.

---

Самый оптимальный вариант решения, как по мне, создать разметку с `TextView`, которые будут выглядеть, как элементы `ListView`. `RecyclerView` найдет их однажды (через метод `findViewById`) и дальше проблем не возникнет — смело вставляйте информацию.

Answer (score 0):

В случае с ListView, была проблема с определением скролла - что именно сейчас скролится, вся страница или только элемент списка?

Решение:
Чтобы создать несколько ListView на одной странице, создайте в файле разметки любое количество виджетов `WidgetStaticListView`. И затем просто инициализируйте в коде каждый из них, добавив к ним адаптер.

Например:

Создаем класс `WidgetStaticListView` и размещаем в него код (на этой странице ниже).
В файле разметки создаем, например, ТРИ элемента `WidgetStaticListView` внутри элемента `ScroolView`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ваш_пакет.WidgetStaticListView
        android:id="@+id/wsListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </ваш_пакет.WidgetStaticListView>

    <ваш_пакет.WidgetStaticListView
        android:id="@+id/wsListView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </ваш_пакет.WidgetStaticListView>

 <ваш_пакет.WidgetStaticListView
        android:id="@+id/wsListView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </ваш_пакет.WidgetStaticListView>

</ScrollView>
```

В активити пишем для списков:

```
WidgetStaticListView wslv1 = (WidgetStaticListView) findViewById(R.id.wsListView1);
WidgetStaticListView wslv2 = (WidgetStaticListView) findViewById(R.id.wsListView2);
WidgetStaticListView wslv3 = (WidgetStaticListView) findViewById(R.id.wsListView3);
//отдельно создаем адаптеры и присваиваем их к этим спискам
wslv1.setAdapter(adapter1);
wslv2.setAdapter(adapter2);
wslv3.setAdapter(adapter3);
```

Код класса `WidgetStaticListView`:

```
//some listview on one view

//add in xml-layout
//
//<...your_path.. .WidgetStaticListView
//                android:id="@+id/wsListView"
//                android:layout_width="match_parent"
//                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
//                android:orientation="vertical">
//            </...your_path.. .WidgetStaticListView>

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class WidgetStaticListView extends LinearLayout {
    protected Adapter adapter;
    protected Observer observer = new Observer(this);

    public WidgetStaticListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public WidgetStaticListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setAdapter(Adapter adapter) {
        if (this.adapter != null)
            this.adapter.unregisterDataSetObserver(observer);
        this.adapter = adapter;
        adapter.registerDataSetObserver(observer);
        observer.onChanged();
    }

    private class Observer extends DataSetObserver {
        WidgetStaticListView context;

        public Observer(WidgetStaticListView context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            List<View> oldViews = new ArrayList<View>(context.getChildCount());
            for (int i = 0; i < context.getChildCount(); i++)
                oldViews.add(context.getChildAt(i));

            Iterator<View> iter = oldViews.iterator();
            context.removeAllViews();
            for (int i = 0; i < context.adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                View convertView = iter.hasNext() ? iter.next() : null;
                context.addView(context.adapter.getView(i, convertView, context));
            }
            super.onChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onInvalidated() {
            context.removeAllViews();
            super.onInvalidated();
        }
    }
}
```

Примечание: скорее всего, вам удастся повторить этот трюк и для `RecyclerView`. Удачи!